# SQL - Removing rows before a specific date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query that returns the output below:

|  **name**  |  **cost date**  |  **cost**  |  **sale date**  |  **sale**  |

We generate sales as a test run before any costs come in. We would only like to select sales only occurring on or after cost date. Is there any way to omit these sales occurring before the cost date from our final output?

Answer (score 2):

SQL is very good at this kind of thing! You can use a `WHERE` condition like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table_name
WHERE  sale_date >= cost_date
```

Comment: Ha!  Indeed it is... (to OP - that's pretty much one of the foundational pillars of SQL)